# Can I make git-svn use my existing ssh-agent for credentials?

Tags: git, git-svn, ssh-agent

ETA: Turns out I may have the wrong end of the stick.

Collabnet SVN stores its client certificate credentials not by using `ssh-agent`, but with `gnome-keyring` (or `kwallet`, or other platform-specific keyrings).  This, in turn, leads to a [longstanding open bug](http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/git-svn-always-prompted-for-passphrase-with-subversion-1-6-td3520498.html) in Git where it won't try to use some of the various Subversion authorization providers that are available.  This is a problem [all over](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/git/+bug/637974), and I'm not even sure who would actually be responsible for getting it fixed.  So for now, it's not a SO problem.

---

I'm using git-svn to work against a subversion repo that uses client certificate authentication over HTTPS.  I've got SVN set up properly to use certs, and command-line svn always prompts for my certificate password when I do a remote operation (because I could never figure out how to have it use ssh-agent to access credentials).

Now that I'm using git-svn, remote operations (like `git-svn fetch`) still prompt for a password each time, but this time using an X dialog titled "OpenSSH", which is identical to the ssh-agent dialog I get when I first log on each day.  So it looks like git-svn is trying to use ssh-agent (yay!) but for some reason can't get access to the one that runs at session level (boo!) and thus needs to start its own... for each invocation of git-svn.

Is there something I'm missing that lets me "point" git-svn at the running agent and thus avoid typing a password every time I want to fetch?

Comment: What OS are you using?  What agent?

Comment: RHEL 5.6.  And maybe I don't know enough about it, but I'm just running `/usr/bin/ssh-agent` in my sessions file, which (as I said in the post) pops up a prompt for my cert password at login, then lets me SSH as often as I want without a prompt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer for now is "file a bug report, Git is broken", as far as I can tell.